SvelteKit streamed promises sometimes return 0 elements and sometimes a filled array
I have written the below code in a +page.server.ts file:
const mediaItemComments = mediaItemComment.getByRequestId(params.id);

return {
    request,
    streamed: {
        record,
        mediaItemComments,
        client: user.get(request.clientId)
    }
}

This uses the getByRequestId method, defined in db.ts:
export const mediaItemComment = {
    getByRequestId: async(id: string) => {
        const ref = await db
          .collection('mediaItemComments')
          .get()

        const comments = ref.docs.map((doc) => ({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() })) // todo: add ts
        console.log('DB.TS ran and fetched these comments: ', comments.length)
        return comments;
   }
}

My page.svelte file uses this Promise as the streamedComments prop to other components:
<script>
    ....
    export let data;
</script>

{#each...}
    <Art index={i + 1} {art} streamedComments={data.streamed.mediaItemComments} {record} />
{/each}

The Art component uses the SpecialCarousel component, which uses the MediaItemModal component as follows:
<script>
    let comments = []
    onMount(async () => {
        try {
            console.log('onMount in MediaItemModal running with streamedComments', streamedComments)
            comments = await streamedComments
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Failed to load comments:', error)
        }
    })
</script>

Sometimes, the Promise resolves to only have 8 comments in it, while the other times, it only has 0 comments. When I open the app, 10% of the time it will show all the comments in the Firebase collection, while the other times it will return 0 comments in the Promise on the frontend (when I log it on the browser). However, on the db.ts file, it is always logged as returning 8 elements from the database. Not sure what's happening here. Please guide.
I see comments loading. I refresh the page. Now they no longer load. On changing code randomly by adding spaces, and refreshing, sometimes it shows the comments for 1 refresh, but then not for the other ones. Am very confused here.

Ok guys I fixed it.
In the db.ts, I simplified what I wrote in the question. I was actually getting the comments, then adding another key to each element in the array.
// ...[previous code in question, db.ts]
comments.forEach(async (comment) => {
    let commenter = {}
    if (comment.commenterType === 'user') {
        commenter = await user.get(comment.commenterId)
    } else if (comment.commenterType === 'designer') {
        commenter = await designer.get(comment.commenterId)
    }
    const formattedComment = { ...comment, commenter }
    assortedComments.push(formattedComment)
})

return assortedComments

All I had to do was change this to a for (comment of comments) format, so that it would handle the processing correctly and wait for the async operations to be completed, before moving ahead and returning the assortedComments:
for (const comment of comments) {
  let commenter = {}
  if (comment.commenterType === 'user') {
    commenter = await user.get(comment.commenterId)
  } else if (comment.commenterType === 'designer') {
    commenter = await designer.get(comment.commenterId)
  }
  const formattedComment = { ...comment, commenter }
  assortedComments.push(formattedComment)
}

